# Python thread blocks after getting from Queue

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading

I have a list of emails i want to validate from same domain. Firstly, I check if the domain allows verfication or is a catchall (accepts all email user as valid). E.g Assuming `[a@domain.com, b@domain.com]` is the `list`, I will check if `foo-fake@domain.com` would be valid, if it is return from function.

If not use multiple thread to verify all emails in list - if all fail return the last item. If one is valid and other threads are running stop them and return the valid one.

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading
import smtplib

class MailWorker(threading.Thread):
    kill = False
    def __init__(self, in_que, out_que):
        super(MailWorker, self).__init__()
        self.in_que = in_que
        self.out_que = out_que

    def run(self):
        while True:
            email, host = self.in_que.get()
            self.test_email(email, host)
            self.in_que.task_done()


    def test_email(self, email, host, retry=0):
        status = "Unknown"
        code = None
        rand = "info@example.com"
        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP(timeout=20)
            server.connect(host, 25)
            server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
            code, response = server.docmd('mail from:', "<{}>".format(rand))
            code, response = server.docmd('rcpt to:', "<{}>".format(email))
            if code == 421:
                while retry < 3:
                    if retry >= 3:
                        server.quit()
                        self.out_que.put((email, "Service not available", code))
                    server.quit()
                    return self.test_email(email, host, retry=retry)
            if code == 250:
                status = 'valid'
                self.out_que.put((email, status, code,))
        except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
            while retry < 3:
                retry += 1
                status = "(SMTP Disconnected Unexpectedly) Retry # {}".format(retry)
                code = -2
                time.sleep(2)
                if retry >= 3:
                    self.out_que.put((email, "SMTP Disconnected", code))
                else:
                    return self.test_email(email, host, retry=retry)
            self.out_que.put((email, status, code,))

def check_email(emails, domain, index=0, is_main=False):
    email = status = code = None
    in_que = Queue(maxsize=10)
    out_que = Queue(maxsize=10)

    if 'brighthouse' in domain:
        host = 'brighthouse-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com'
    else:
        host = 'eu-smtp-inbound-2.mimecast.com'

    # is it a catchall? if it is i want to return from the function ---  
    # If the email is valid then it is not a catchall all so execute line 91
    # till return checking multipe emails in threads but exit when one valid is found else do all email in list
    if not is_main: # check if the email is main
        in_que.put(('JUNK_EMAIL_CANT_BE_REAL_fewfwewefew@' + domain, host)) # put rubbish email in thread if valid it is a catchall, then exit
        for i in range(1): 
            mw = MailWorker(in_que, out_que)
            print mw
            print "*" * 20
            mw.daemon = True
            mw.start()
            print mw.getName()
        print in_que.qsize(), " in queue size"
        print out_que.qsize(), " out queue size"

        print "*" * 20
        email, status, code = out_que.get()
        print "Contet = ", email, status, code


        if code == 250:
            print 'Domain is a Catch-All.  email: %s host: %s' % (emails[0], host)
            MailWorker.kill = True
            return emails, "catchall", -99, index
        elif code == -1:
            return email, status, code, index
    # in_que.join()
    # out_que.join()

    for index, email_address in enumerate(emails):
        in_que.put((email_address, host,))

    for i in range(10):
        mw = MailWorker(in_que, out_que)
        mw.daemon = True
        mw.start()
    while not out_que.empty():
        email, status, code, index = out_que.get()
        if code == 250:
            MailWorker.kill = True
            return email, status, code, index
    in_que.join()
    out_que.join()
    return email, status, code, index


emails_list = [
    ['fred@brighthouse.co.uk', 'joe.fred@brighthouse.co.uk', 'joe@brighthouse.co.uk'],

    ['fred@cqs.com', 'joe.fred@cqs.com', 'joe@cqs.com']
]

for emails in emails_list:
    domain = emails[0].split('@')[1]

    print(check_email(emails, domain))
```

My expectation is for the next list item to run.

**The result with the above code is:**

```
# CODE FREEZES and DOESN'T RUN SECOND item IN EMAILS_LIST -- SEE output

        """
        <MailWorker(Thread-1, initial)>                                                                                                                                                        
        ********************                                                                                                                                                                   
        Thread-1                                                                                                                                                                               
        1  in queue size                                                                                                                                                                       
        0  out queue size                                                                                                                                                                      
        ********************                                                                                                                                                                   
        Contet =  rubbish_fQ94hEAi93@brighthouse.co.uk valid 250                                                                                                                               
        Domain is a Catch-All.  email: fred@brighthouse.co.uk host: brighthouse-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com                                                                              
        (['fred@brighthouse.co.uk', 'joe.fred@brighthouse.co.uk', 'joe@brighthouse.co.uk'], 'catchall', -99, 0)                                                                                
        <MailWorker(Thread-2, initial)>                                                                                                                                                        
        ********************                                                                                                                                                                   
        Thread-2                                                                                                                                                                               
        0  in queue size                                                                                                                                                                       
        0  out queue size                                                                                                                                                                      
        ********************    <---- code blocks here                                                                                                                                                                        

        """
```

Comment: (1) `get()` on an empty queue blocks (waits) until a new item in the queue is available, so you are creating unnecessary waiting threads. (2) `join()` on a queue blocks until `task_done()` was called for each processed items which isn't done for `out_que`

Comment: @MichaelButscher I played with it a bit and added `self.out_que.task_done()` in run afer the `self.n_que.task_done()` but got error saying `'task_done() called too many times'`

Comment: As the documentation clearly states there must be exactly one call to `task_done()` for each call to `get()`. So you should place it somewhere after `out_que.get()` or you don't use `join()` at all.